# What is meant by unique cardinality constraint in this example?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram

## ER Diagram

[image]

## Basic schema

[image]

## Unique constraints ?

[image]

I am somewhat confused by what exactly `school of Located_at` or `school of Principle_of` is meant to be? I understand the idea here is to denote the 1..1 cardinality by enforcing uniqueness but isn't the uniqueness inherent by the choice of key ( excluding weak entity sets ) as it being the unique identifier? In other words, for example with `Located_at` why isn't the schema just `Located_at(*address_id* -> Address, name -> Preschool)` in what way does `school -> Preschool` differ from that or is it just some kind of alias for the key ?

Same applies to the other choices of worker, principle, child ? They don't appear to be keys of any kind so I don't exactly understand what they are ?

I just started my DB course so I am very new to all this, I apologize if this is just me missing some fundamentals.